# min/max width and object-fit:cover

Tags: css

I have 2 images with both `100vh` and `50vw`, I also have the `object-fit:cover`, everything works, but when a picture is smaller than a certain size the other one gets bigger, i tried adding

`min-width: 1000px`
`max-width: 1100px`
to my code but then `object-fit: cover` doesen't work, so when i zoom out it leaves a gap at the end.

For context, some of my images are < 1000px in width so when they appear it leaves a gap at the right end of the page

Is the only way to fix this to get images > 1000px?

here is my code:

```css
#item1 { 
  width:50vw; 
  height:100vh; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  min-height: 973px; 
  min-width: 1000px; 
  object-fit: cover; 
}

#item2 { 
  width:50vw; 
  height:100vh; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  min-height: 973px; 
  min-width: 1000px; 
  object-fit: cover; 
}

#item1, #item2 {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

.the-images { 
  display: flex; 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 10; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media query was not working so if anyone is facing the same problem here is what I did:

```
#item1,
#item2 {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 50vw; 
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

#item1, #item2 {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
.the-images { 
  display: flex; 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 10; 
top: 0; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0; 
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw; 
overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

I added `flex: 1` to distrubute space between images, instead of adding `min-width` in `px` i added it in `vw` and it worked, don't forget to set your image container to `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`

Answer (score 0):

When you set a min-width that is larger than the original image size, the image will stretch, and object-fit: cover won't work as expected.

You can try media queries to set different styles for different screen sizes, as per the CSS below:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #item1, #item2 {
    min-width: 1000px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  #item1, #item2 {
    min-width: auto;
  }
}
```

Or if you're up to it, Use JS to dynamically set min-width, but try the CSS first.

Edit: The most foolproof way would be to ensure that all your images meet the minimum width requirement of 1000px before using them, which is a pretty simple process using paint 3d or whatever.

Comment: when ipaste that in `object-fit: cover` doesent work, should i add in js

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query and set checkpoint of size that you want your element get changes.